# Proving $2\cot(x)\csc(2x) - \cot^2(x) = 1$

Tags: trigonometry

Good day! I have this given trigonometric identity which is
$$2\cot(x)\csc(2x) - \cot^2(x) = 1$$

I may need to verify this one if the identities will equal to 1 or not but I'm not sure how I can verify it clearly since I complicate further the identities. I think I need some helpful guides from all of you in order for me to resolve my confusion on these trigonometric identities.

Your responses would be highly appreciated!!
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always easier to prove identities when they're all changed to $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.
$$2\cot(x)\csc(2x) - \cot^2(x) = 1 \\
\frac{2\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \times \frac{1}{\sin(2x)} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} = 1 \\
\frac{2\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \times \frac{1}{2\cos(x)\sin(x)} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} = 1 \\
\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} = 1 \\
\frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} = 1 \\
\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} = 1 \\
1 = 1
$$

Comment: ohh nice!!! I see what you did there!! You used the quotient identity for the cot to transform it into cos(x) / sin(x) also on cot^2 cos^2(x) / sin^2(x)  would be  then you also transformed sin 2x by I guess using the sum identity for sine (sin(x+x) which to cut it shorter, it transforms into sin2(x)=2sin(x)cos(x) ) .
Thank you very much for the response!!!!!!!!!
It helped me a lot!!!

Comment: There you go!! Straight to the point response..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\csc(2x)=\frac {1}{\sin(2x)}=\frac {1}{2\sin x \cos x}$

Answer (score 0):

The identity is equivalent to
$2\cdot\frac{1}{\tan x}\cdot \frac{1}{\sin 2x}-\frac{1}{\tan^2x}=1$.

Just use $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$ and some other basic properties.